# Can server script detect if a form is posted with submit button or with javascript:Submit()

Tags: javascript, forms, post, server-side

This problem is keeping me busy all week and I find little to nothing on the net ...

What I want to do is simple ... on my own website, create a server side PHP script that makes a login to another website with valid credentials and downloads a file that I want to process.

I use curl_init(), curl_setopt() and curl_exec() in trying to achieve that. It doesn't work.

So I stripped down that webpage to figure out what's wrong.
As you can see in the html code, the form's action event is the url to retrieve the file, when correct credentials are submitted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >

<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="http://otherwebsite/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/export_file.aspx?id=xxxxxxx" >
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
        function Submit_Form()
        {
           document.form1.Login$UserName.value="myname";
           document.form1.Login$Password.value="mypassword";
           //document.form1.Login$LoginButton.click();
           document.form1.submit();
        }
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="Login$UserName" value="myname" />
<input type="hidden" name="Login$Password" value="mypassword" />

<input name="Login$LoginButton" type="submit" />
<br /><a href="javascript:Submit_Form();">Login</a>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now here is where it gets weird.
If I press the button, it works and I receive the download file.
If I click the hyperlink, i get a page saying to login properly.
When I uncomment the javascript line : click() it works too.

So it comes down to this :
Why does the button submit work and javascript submit doesn't work ?
Is there a way that the other website's server check how the form was posted ?
Thank you for your thoughts !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the button, its name is included in the POST request because it's a named `submit` button. When you use the link, the button's name doesn't get passed in the POST data.

You could probably spoof the button when you use the link by having a hidden field with the name the button should have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Login$UserName" value="myname" />
<input type="hidden" name="Login$Password" value="mypassword" />
<input type="hidden" name="Login$LoginButton" />
```

Note it doesn't need a value because the button it replaces doesn't have a value setting its text. Just including it should be sufficient.

Comment: YES, this works too !
Solution was so simple, yet so many time lost !
Thank you all for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Why not have another hidden field called `js_submitted` with a value of `false`, and in your `Submit_Form()` function, set it to `true` before firing the `submit()` method? Then, in PHP (for example), you could look for `$_GET/$_POST['js_submitted']` to determine which submission method was used.

Comment: TY for your answer
It doesn't work.
I added :
html : <input type="hidden" name="js_submitted" />
javascript : document.form1.js_submitted=true;

Comment: first, in your html, set `js_submitted`'s `value="false"`, then in JS, change the value with `document.form1.js_submitted.value = 'true';`.

Comment: TY for your answer
Your post wasn't complete when i read it :)
Now I changed the html code.
I will try to post that to my own server tomorrow and check the variable result ... bed time now :)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to check that the button was posted with the submit. Maybe they are checking for this.

Comment: Exactly my thought also ... but how could they do that ?

Comment: They could perform this check in a number of ways on the server. The easiest being, just check that 3 form elements were submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very easy to find out when a button submits a form, and that is exactly what the site might be doing.

A button is a form control and so, when a form is submitted, the button state is submitted as well. What this means is, when you check the form object on the server that receives the `post`, you will see it contains a key with the same name as the `button` and it's value is set to the `value` attribute of your button.

Consider you have a `form`:

```
<form id="form1" action="abc.asp" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Opt123" />
    <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Opt456" />
    <a href="javascript:Submit_Form();">Send</a>
</form>
```

I am not a `PHP` person, so code might not be the best:

```
$item = $_POST['btn'];
```

In this case, value of `$item` will be either *Opt123* or *Opt456* depending on the button pressed, whereas if the link is pressed, then it would be a `null` or `PHP` equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the submit button is part of the form, the browser only sends its `name=value` pair as part of the post data if the button was actually clicked. When you call the `.submit()` method from Javascript, your browser sends the data `Login$Username=myname&Login$Password=mypassword` to the server. But when you actually click the button, it sends `Login$Username=myname&Login$Password=mypassword&Login$LoginButton=`. As you can see, it would then be very easy for the server to differentiate between the two.

So, you can trick the form into always sending that element by making it hidden. In `Submit_Form`, just before you say `document.form1.submit();`, add this:

```
var sbtn_hid = document.createElement('input');
sbtn_hid.type = 'hidden';
sbtn_hid.name = 'Login$LoginButton';
sbtn_hid.value = '';
document.form1.appendChild(sbtn_hid);
```

That adds a hidden form element with the same name as the submit button, so the server won't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: YES !!! TY so much !
That did the trick ...
My next challenge is to implement that on the server side, but that's a different story.